# How do you send a photo from your photo files? The enter key does not act as a submit key

Tags: ipad, photos

How do you send a photo from my photo files? 
The enter key does not act as a submit key

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! The question is lacking key details and the problem intent is not clear. Kindly edit your question to add relevant details so that you can get relevant answers quickly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can send a photo from the Photos app on your iPad.

To send photos, you can:

1. Launch the Photos app
2. Tap on the photo you want to send (or, in the case of multiple photos, tap on the *Select* option and select the photos you want to send)
3. Tap on the *share* icon (see image below)

[image]

4. Now select *how* you want to send it (e.g. via Message, Mail, etc)

You can also send photos directly from *within* apps. By way of example, you can compose a new email message and tapping on the screen will give you the option to *Insert Photo or Video*. Doing this will open the Photos app from where you can select the photos/videos you want to attach to your email. Likewise, within the Messages app you can tap on the *camera* icon to be presented with a choice of taking new photos or accessing existing photos in your Photos library.